# React: How Do I get the value of a custom TextInput Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have code for a custom TextInput component and I want to use this component for both a username and password value for a login screen, however, I don't know how to retrieve the value of the text input for a specific instance.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, StyleSheet, View, ImagePropTypes } from 'react-native';

const TextInputCustom = (props) => {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      placeholder={props.name}
      style={styles.textInput}
      onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value}
    />
    </View>
  );
}
```

After Importing I created in my login screen

```
<TextInputCustom name="Username"/>
<TextInputCustom name="Password"/>
```

How do I get the value so that I can assign it to a variable for each TextInputCustom instance?

Comment: Do you have access to APIs of that component? That will be a good place to start looking. Usually, you have `onChange` handler. I also see you have `onChangeText` as prop but since you still are facing issue, i'm assuming its not working. So try to check the API and use correct prop

Comment: have you tried using callback function?

Comment: [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `value` and `onChange` to the parent level:

```
import { TextInput, StyleSheet, View, ImagePropTypes } from 'react-native';

const TextInputCustom = (props) => {
  const {value, onChange} = props;

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      placeholder={props.name}
      style={styles.textInput}
      onChangeText={text => onChange(text)}
      value={value}
    />
    </View>
  );
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
<TextInputCustom name="Username" value={username} onChange={onUsernameChange} />
<TextInputCustom name="Password" value={password} onChange={onPasswordChange} />
```

This is the practice that is used in general for simple components. You don't need to handle the value in the component level, but in the component that is using your custom component.